# Endlessly & smoothly horizontal scroll an HTML table with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

An HTML table exceeds page width, by far. There's a slider to scroll contents automatically.

Is there a way to achieve automatic scrolling (left-to right), smoothly?

Basically, with no user intervention, contents will scroll left to right, endlessly and smoothly

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/

Comment: Very similar here, but works with images... http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/horizontal.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add a piece of javascript:

```
setInterval(function(){
     document.getElementById("yourdiv").scrollLeft += 3;
}, 20);
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/UPLJs/

Or you can use a jQuery plugin, as stated above.

Update for a stop on hover and start after 1 second:

Javascript:

```
var intervalId;

    setTimeout(function(){
        intervalId = setInterval(startScroll, 10);
    }, 1000);

startScroll = function() {     
        document.getElementById("yourdiv").scrollLeft +=3;
}

stopScroll = function () {
   clearInterval(intervalId); 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="yourdiv" onmouseover="stopScroll()">
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UPLJs/3/

If you have any questions, please feel free to ask them.

Comment: Semy off topic: as the table is quite big (built with Javascript code) and i takes n seconds to complete loading depending on computer and network speed, how can I allow scrolling to start only some seconds (5?) after table completion?

Comment: Another question: possible to halt scrolling on hover?

Comment: You can set a timer function to let it wait a certain amount of seconds before executing. As for the hover, yes this is possible with a simple if statement. I can create a sample for you tomorrow, as I am now not able to on my mobile phone.